How to fix printing macro in excel
I am trying to print out 18 tabs. They are each named Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, etc. If there is no data in cell (BB2) for a specific page, then I do not want to print it out. Any advice, because I keep getting errors. The data in these item sheets are pulled from separate tabs in excel. Any advice on fixing this.
Sub PrintItemSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 18
        Sheets("Item " & i).ws.Range("BB2").Value < > "" Then ws.PrintOut
    Next i

End Sub


What's ws? Are you missing an If in your actual code, or just in the question?

Still not going through. Highlighted the Sub line and the <> is showing compile error

Make that:
Sub PrintItemSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 18
        With Sheets("Item " & i)
           If .Range("BB2").Value <> "" Then
               .PrintOut
           End If
       End With
    Next i
End Sub


I need the same function but now adding in on the to print macro is to on print page 3 specifically. How to do this formula, while adding the print page three only rule?

.PrintOut From:=3,To:=3,Copies:=1
